# Centos VM with Docker getting host unreachable when trying to connect to itself

Tags: networking, docker, vmware, docker-compose, centos7

I have Docker running on a Centos VM, with bridged network.  running

```
ifconfig
```

shows that my VM gets a valid IP address.  Now I'm running some software within a docker container/image (which works within other docker/networking configurations). Some of my code running in the docker container uses SSL Connection (java) to connect to itself.  In all other run configurations, this works perfectly.  But when running in bridged mode with Centos VM and docker-compose, I'm getting an SSL Connect exception, error:  Host unreachable.  I can ping to and ssh into the VM with the same IP address and this all works fine.  I'm sorry that I can't post actual setup/code and scripts as it's too much to post and it's also proprietary.

I'm baffled by this - why am I getting Host Unreachable in the aforementioned configuration?

Comment: "connect to itself" means what? `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: meaning using the machine's IP address OR localhost.  Either one fails.  This is because docker seems to have created a set of IP addresses for each container.  But how can I set it up with docker-compose yml to use the SAME IP for all containers so that they can talk to each other and outside access is possible?  This is causing a lot of problems for me.  I tried to setup the networking using "bridge" mode, but this causes other problems with redirects not being found and again, the attempt to connect via the machine's IP to the container fails.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose file? And are you saying that the same Docker container running on Ubuntu works but on Centos it fails?

Comment: 2 setups:  One on my mac, with docker installed on mac, and created a "default" vmware docker machine.  This one works fine with no additional network configuration.  IE, my application can send messages to itself on its "external" IP and it can talk to its cassandra and jdbc containers. The other setup that I have is a Centos VM with docker running on the VM (no docker-machine).  This setup (upon closer inspection as to why it was failing) reveals that docker has created a network for the containers and therefore app container is unable to http to itself via its external IP, nor localhost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FYI, I resolved the problem on centos by using the default "bridged" containers provided by Docker, but adding the following to my firewalld configuration:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --add-interface=docker0
firewall-cmd --reload
service firewalld restart
```

You might also need to open up a port to allow external communication, like so:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: When doing this, and trying to restart docker on redhat I get an error as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1608853/docker-daemon-error-after-updating-docker

Basically his answer and your answer are the exact opposite.
Did you have the same problem restarting docker? If so, is this a workable solution.

Has docker improved their firewalld support the last 5 years? I still seem to be having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to an Ubuntu VM, because switching my docker compose to the default "bridged" network broke my aliases, which I really needed

The only remaining question here is why after configuring firewalld, a user-configured network on docker-compose cannot access the external IP, forcing us to switch to the default bridged network

Comment: Did you get answer to this? I am also facing same issue. a user-configured network on docker-compose cannot access the external IP